# Quartz.net windows service does not execute job which referencesSSRS web service

Tags: reporting-services, tcp, windows-services, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have used two web references of ssrs reporting execution service to generate the report.  I am using quartz.net windows service for scheduling ssrs reports. My Windows service is working when I use the StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler() but  as I execute my job in a Quartz service remotely and use GetScheduler() , it's not working.

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{


        RS2005.ReportingService2005 rs;
        RE2005.ReportExecutionService rsExec;



        // Create a new proxy to the web service
        rs = new RS2005.ReportingService2005();
        rsExec = new RE2005.ReportExecutionService();

        // Authenticate to the Web service using Windows credentials
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        rsExec.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        rs.Url = "http://127.0.0.1:7001/ReportServer/reportservice2005.asmx";
        rsExec.Url = "http://127.0.0.1:7001/ReportServer/reportexecution2005.asmx";

        string historyID = null;
        string deviceInfo = null;
        string format = "PDF";
        Byte[] results;
        string encoding = String.Empty;
        string mimeType = String.Empty;
        string extension = String.Empty;
        RE2005.Warning[] warnings = null;
        string[] streamIDs = null;

        // Path of the Report - XLS, PDF etc.
        string fileName = "samplereport.pdf";
        // Name of the report - Please note this is not the RDL file.
        string _reportName = @"/reports_Debug/reportname";
        string _historyID = null;
        bool _forRendering = false;
        RS2005.ParameterValue[] _values = null;
        RS2005.DataSourceCredentials[] _credentials = null;
        RS2005.ReportParameter[] _parameters = null;

        try
        {
            _parameters = rs.GetReportParameters(_reportName, _historyID, _forRendering, _values, _credentials);
            RE2005.ExecutionInfo ei = rsExec.LoadReport(_reportName, historyID);
            RE2005.ParameterValue[] parameters = new RE2005.ParameterValue[8];

            if (_parameters.Length > 0)
            {

                parameters[0] = new RE2005.ParameterValue();
                parameters[0].Name = "FromDate";
                parameters[0].Value = "1/1/2016";
                parameters[1] = new RE2005.ParameterValue();
                parameters[1].Name = "ToDate";
                parameters[1].Value = "1/21/2016"; // June

            }
            rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");

            results = rsExec.Render(format, deviceInfo,
                      out extension, out encoding,
                      out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);

            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
            {
                stream.Write(results, 0, results.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

Comment: Found the Answer:  service require special permission to interact on web through http. Service's property -> use the local account credentials or install service as administrator has solved problem.